# firefox browser is not running after new profile in Selenium

Tags: webdriver

I have custom framework in selenium web driver.

My Firefox crashed and asked me to create a new profile.

Now, when running the script, Firefox launches but not running.

I get the error: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055

can you help please

Comment: it was Firefox upgrade issue, Selenium 47 is not compatible with Firefox 44 and up

Answer (score 0):

it was Firefox upgrade issue, Selenium 47 is not compatible with Firefox 44 and up